# Geodesic in local coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

A Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{X}$ contains, for certain coordinate chart $(U, \varphi)$, the (local) coordinate map $\varphi$ that maps a neighborhood of coordinate $p$ to an Euclidean space $\tilde{U}$, which represents its tangential space $T_p \mathcal{X}$. My question regards a geodesic differential equation in local coordinates.

In case of a submerged surface $\mathcal{X}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the geodesic equation over $\mathcal{X}$ is given by the flow solution $\phi(t)$ of differential equation below:

$\ddot{c} + \Gamma(c, \dot{c}) = 0$

Is there a way to represent the equality above in coordinates $U$ such that the flow $\omega(t)$ gives the flow $\phi(t)$ by equality $\phi = \varphi(\omega)$?

$\ddot{u} + I(u, \dot{u}) = 0$

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with "submerged" surfaces. The actual [geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Mathematical_expression) in local coordinates is written in terms of Chrisfoffel symbols.

Comment: Ok. I will state in less expert terms: Given a geodesic curve equation in cartesian coordinates and a coordinate transformation $\varphi$ from space $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, define the geodesic equation in this new two-dimensional coordinate chart.

Comment: I don't think the problem pointed out my @MoisheKohan reduces to a misunderstanding of any expert term

Comment: Your comment is unclear. Do you know the geodesic equation in the local coordinates? If so, why do you have a problem in writing this equation? Do you have trouble computing the Christoffel symbols? Consider writing your question in Portuguese and posting it in addition to the English translation.

Comment: Great advice! I thank you sincerely. I pulled back myself how to perform the geodesic curve computation of parametrization $\varphi(x) = 0$ by means of some coordinate chart $x = \eta(u)$, for dim$(x)$ > dim$(u)$. The answer is to obtain the geodesic in the same systematic in $u$ as for $x$ throughout $(\varphi \circ \eta) (u) = 0$.